# Asp.Net Core HealthChecks HTTP Timeout

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, health-check

I have a healthcheck (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-5.0) that merely runs a longer range of SQL queries , a lot of them, after 100 seconds it times out with an error.

```
HResult":-2146233029,"Message":"The request was canceled due 
to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds
elapsing.","Source":"System.Net.Http","InnerException":
{"Type":"System.TimeoutException","HResult":-
2146233083,"Message":"The operation was 
canceled.","Source":null,"InnerException":
{"Type":"System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException","HResult":-
2146233029,"Message":"The operation was 
canceled.","Source":"System.Net.Http","InnerException":
{},"CancellationToken":"CancellationRequested: 
true","Task":"null"}},"CancellationToken":"CancellationRequested: 
true","Task":"null"}
```

So I tried to add a timespan

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
.AddCheck<Sys_Version_VersionHealthCheck>("Version"
, HealthStatus.Unhealthy, tags: new[] 
{sys_version_settings.LogTag }, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5, 0, 0));
```

But it seems to have no effect.

Is there a setting around the HealthChecks that can be set to increase this?

Comment: The issue happens when you send the http request via HttpClient, so you should change the HttpClient's timeout property, instead of the healthcheck, refer the following article:[HttpClient.Timeout Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-5.0) and [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: But... where?  the healthcheck itself contains no calling code it only queries a db.

Comment: can you post the related code about the Sys_Version_VersionHealthCheck?

Comment: If you make en empty healthcheck class MyHealthCheck and have a loop in there that waits for 100 seconds  it should popup